# Subsequence of a convergent sequence that doesn't converge

Tags: real-analysis

I've got a theorem that say that if the sequence $(x_n)$ converge to $\ell$, all subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converge, converge to $\ell$.

So, is there subsequence that doesn't converge ? If yes, could you give me an example.

Comment: Your theorem says that __all__ subsequences of $(x_n)$ converge. That means that there isn't any subsequence of $(x_n)$ that doesn't converge ... Or did I misunderstand the question ?

Comment: My theorem says precisely that ** all convergente subsequence converge to $\ell$.** What I interpret like there existe subsequence that doesn't converge.

Answer (score 5):

The correct theorem is "$\{x_n\}$ converges to $l$ if and only if all subsequences converge to $l$. So there is no subsequence that does not converge to $l$.